Turning a Vec<Row> into a Vec<Hashmap> for each Row
I am using the library tiberius to query data from SQL Server.
I have constructed some fake data that roughly imitates the structure of a single result (which returns multiple Row structs in a Vec).
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Row {
    columns: Vec<Column>,
    data: TokenRow,
    result_index: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TokenRow {
    data: Vec<Option<String>>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Column {
    name: String,
    column_type: String,
}

fn main() {

    let mut data: Vec<Row> = Vec::from([
        Row {
            columns: Vec::from([
                Column {
                    name: String::from("foo"),
                    column_type: String::from("string"),
                },
                Column {
                    name: String::from("bar"),
                    column_type: String::from("string"),
                },
            ]),
            data: TokenRow {
                data: Vec::from([
                    Some(String::from("hello")),
                    Some(String::from("world")),
                ]),
            },
            result_index: 0,
        }
    ]);
    
    dbg!(data);
    
    let mut vals: Vec<(String, String)> = Vec::new();
    for r in data {
        let res = r
            .columns
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(i, col)| {
                let col_name = col.name; // find column name
                let col_value = r.data.data[i]; // find value at that index
                (col_name, col_value)
            })
            .collect();
            
        vals.push(res)
    }
    dbg!(vals);

        
    // the ugly way
    // let mut m = HashMap::new();
    // m.insert(String::from("foo"), String::from("hello"));
    // m.insert(String::from("bar"), String::from("world"));
    // println!("{:?}", m);
}

Basically, I'd like to convert this Vec<Row> into a Vec<HashMap> using some iterator or map patterns. The normal way using tiberius would be to get the result based on the column label, but that seems verbose.
Desired end HashMap result for a single Row entity:
{
    "foo": "hello",
    "bar": "world"
}

I attached some scratchwork in Rust Playground Here

If you change vals from Vec<(String, String)> to Vec<HashMap<String, String>> then I'm pretty sure this will just compile. You can collect into vals as well instead of building it up. This is just a double-layered collect exercise.

@cdhowie Looks like I've got it working now Rust Playground.
But I am curious in how you'd do this with a double collect()?

Well you're taking a Vec<Row> and turning it into a Vec<HashMap<_, _>>. So let rows: Vec<HashMap<String, String>> = rows.into_iter().map(|row| row.columns. ... .collect()).collect();. Inner collect builds the maps, outer collect builds the vec of them.
